# Email Send Status is Failed when used in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have created a journey whose entry source is Salesforce Data. When I create a contact record in salesforce it triggers the journey. The contact is meeting the criteria but when it goes to the Email it fails. In the Journey Setting I have chosen default:email as the default email address. Can somebody explain where am I going wrong?

[image: This is the journey]

[image]

I've tried for multiple/different emails but the problem is still there.Also if I use data extension it is working but when I use Salesforce data it fails

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have 2+ email fields in your Event Data would you?

Comment: No I'm using the standard email field of contact

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried test sending the email using the data that is being populated by Salesforce? If you have dynamic content in the email or you are using ampscript - the content and the send itself could be erroring out causing a failed send. Also be sure any ampscript in content blocks are also valid - Marketing Cloud validation tends to only look at the ampscript within the email content itself and may not evaluate variables in content blocks or link attributes.

Comment: There's no ampscript used in this email. I've triend sending a test email and that's working fine only when I send using journey builder it fails